# How to call a function that is defined in a different view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

I'm trying to call the function called "kick". Inside it is a CAAnimation that I am playing on this man I made. So usually I would just call the function in the same view controller as it was made in. But because I have a HUD/overlay scene the displays over my 3D game. And the HUD/overlayscene is made in a different view controller specifically just to set up the HUD I can't get the HUD view controller to Recognize any functions from the Main View Controller.

MainViewController:
Code:

```
   class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, SKSceneDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate{

var HUDView: HUD!

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  //-----Scene-Setup----------
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.scene = FieldScene
    scnView.playing = true
    scnView.loops = true
    self.HUDView = HUD(size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
    scnView.overlaySKScene = self.HUDView
    scnView.delegate = self
    scnView.overlaySKScene!.delegate = self
    scnView.overlaySKScene!.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    scnView.showsStatistics = false

    let GuyScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/The1.dae")
    let Guy: SCNNode = GuyScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Armature", recursively: true)!
    let GuyBody: SCNNode = GuyScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Cube", recursively: true)!
    //----Giveing it a physics---------
    let collisionCapsuleRadius2 = CGFloat(0.1)
    let collisionCapsuleHeight2 = CGFloat(0.1)
    Guy.position = SCNVector3(x: -30.0, y: 30.0, z: 0.0)
    Guy.scale = SCNVector3Make(50, 50, 50)
    Guy.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, 1 )
    Guy.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape:SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNCapsule(capRadius: collisionCapsuleRadius2, height: collisionCapsuleHeight2), options:nil))
    Guy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    Guy.physicsBody?.friction = 0 //
    Guy.physicsBody?.restitution = 1 //bounceness of the object
    Guy.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1 // rotationess
    Guy.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    Guy.physicsBody?.rollingFriction = 0
    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(Guy)
    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(GuyBody)
    }

     //Ok Kick function gets declared right here


    func Kick() {
    //-----Animate-Guy-----Working-Perfectly-----------
    let KickAnimation = CAAnimation.animationWithSceneNamed("art.scnassets/The1Anima.dae")!
    Guy.addAnimation(KickAnimation, forKey: "Go")
    Guy.removeAnimationForKey("Go", fadeOutDuration: 3.0)
   }


 }

   extension CAAnimation {
class func animationWithSceneNamed(name: String) -> CAAnimation? {
    var animation: CAAnimation?
    if let scene = SCNScene(named: name) {
        scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodesUsingBlock({ (child, stop) in
            if child.animationKeys.count > 0 {
                animation = child.animationForKey(child.animationKeys.first!)
                stop.initialize(true)
            }
        })
    }
    return animation
 }
}



  //Ok Below is my HUD/Overlayscene which holds the button that i would like call the function in.


  extension GameViewController {
    // was never used
}

 class HUD: SKScene {
//-----------------Controller-Buttons----------------------
var ButtonA = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"EnhancedAButton")

  override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

    //----A-Button--Creation -------------------
    ButtonA.size = CGSize(width: 7, height: 11)
    ButtonA.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-11.35, -0.6)
    ButtonA.zPosition = 0
    ButtonA.alpha = 0.45
    self.addChild(ButtonA)
    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


   //Ok here is the function I need to put "Kick()"  inside it but when I do it doenst recognize it because the function wasnt declared in this view controller 


func AButtonPressed() {  

}

 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location1 = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location1) == self.ButtonA {
            AButtonPressed()
            print("AButtonPressed")
        }
    }
 }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXOxq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yxPb.png)

Comment: `static func Kick() {
    //-----Animate-Guy-----Working-Perfectly-----------
    let KickAnimation = CAAnimation.animationWithSceneNamed("art.scnassets/The1Anima.dae")!
    Guy.addAnimation(KickAnimation, forKey: "Go")
    Guy.removeAnimationForKey("Go", fadeOutDuration: 3.0)
   }`

Comment: Ok thanks but im getting an error  "static methods may only by declared on type" and then it will tell me to remove the static or it will say  "Use of unresolved identifier 'Guy'

Comment: i just updated the question please take a look i put a image at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is practically the best way to handle this. Other methods are messy while this is the most decoupled natural way to handle it. If you have any questions, let me know.

```
extension GameViewController: GameDelegate {
    func Kick() {
        //-----Animate-Guy-----Working-Perfectly-----------
        let KickAnimation = CAAnimation.animationWithSceneNamed("art.scnassets/The1Anima.dae")!
        Guy.addAnimation(KickAnimation, forKey: "Go")
        Guy.removeAnimationForKey("Go", fadeOutDuration: 3.0)
    }
}

protocol GameDelegate {
    func Kick()
}

class HUD: SKScene {

    var delegate: GameDelegate?

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        //this calls Kick anywhere in the HUD class
        delegate?.Kick()


        //----A-Button--Creation -------------------
        ButtonA.size = CGSize(width: 7, height: 11)
        ButtonA.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-11.35, -0.6)
        ButtonA.zPosition = 0
        ButtonA.alpha = 0.45
        self.addChild(ButtonA)
    }
}
```

after the line that is inside of GameViewController's viewDidLoad()

```
//below this line
self.HUDView = HUD(size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
//add in 
self.HUDView.delegate = self
```

After all of this, is added in, you can delete the copy of Kick that is not in the extension. Both controllers can access the function.

Comment: Ok a little confused so I put the extension and protocol at the top of my HUD controller. then I add the "self.HUDView.delegate = self" line of code in perfectly but then here is were im confused i put the "var delegate: GameDelegate?" right under the "Class HUD: SkScene " but then i get any error saying "cannot override a property with type 'SkSceneDelegate?. And also there is know "viewDidLoad()" in Class HUD

Comment: ok let me try now if its good which im sure its great then ill mark it as the answer

Comment: ok everything's good except for this error which is preventing me from running the program.  On var delelgate: GameDelegate? " error Property 'delegate' with type 'GameDelegate?' can not override a propety with type 'SKSceneDelegate?' (aka ' Optional<SKSceneDelegate>')

Comment: ok i fixed it i had to name the "var delegate: GameDelegate?" to "var gameDelegate: GameDelegate?" but the animation doesnt play for me but there know errors so ill mark as correct

Comment: the extension never gets called even though everything is good with no errors

Comment: Sorry I originally posted it with a couple errors cause I wrote it on this site instead of in xCode. if the delegate has been assigned to be = to self oinside of the viewDidLoad of GameViewController, it will be able to call on any function that is inside of the delegates protocol. The protocol defines which functions from GameViewController that HUD will ahve access to. It isn't necessary to write the extension... that just makes cleaner code. you could have kept the function in the original class and than just added the GameDelegate to this things the class inherits at declaration.

Comment: Look at some guides over delegates and protocols with swift and then check again. My code should be very close to working if it isn't dead on. If kick isn't getting called, put a print statement above where you say delegate?.Kick() and see if it gets called. I only placed it inside of init as an example. You can place it inside of whatever thing will call the delegate function appropriately.